# How to use design of titlepage from scrbook inside scrartcl?

Tags: titles, koma-script, scrbook, scrartcl

The default `titlepage` of documentclass `scrartcl` looks very compressed and not really nice.

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

    \titlehead{Head of titlepage}
    \subject{SUBJECT}
    \title{TITLE}
    \subtitle{A big conclusion of \LaTeX}
    \author{Max Muster \and goLaTeX\thanks{Footnote to author} \and Michael Marks}
    \date{01.01.0001}
    \publishers{Published from Wayne}
    \maketitle

\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of <code>titlepage</code> from <code>scrartcl</code>]

---

In contrast, the `titlepage` of `scrbook` is looking very delicious with its big spaces between the lines:

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\begin{document}

    \titlehead{Head of titlepage}
    \subject{SUBJECT}
    \title{TITLE}
    \subtitle{A big conclusion of \LaTeX}
    \author{Max Muster \and goLaTeX\thanks{Footnote to author} \and Michael Marks}
    \date{01.01.0001}
    \publishers{Published from Wayne}
    \maketitle

\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of <code>titlepage</code> from <code>scrbook</code>]

---

**The question now is:**

How can I use the upper `titlepage` from `scrbook` inside `scrartcl`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the class option `titlepage` (it's turned on by default in `scrbook`).

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

    \titlehead{Head of titlepage}
    \subject{SUBJECT}
    \title{TITLE}
    \subtitle{A big conclusion of \LaTeX}
    \author{Max Muster \and goLaTeX\thanks{Footnote to author} \and Michael Marks}
    \date{01.01.0001}
    \publishers{Published from Wayne}
    \maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: That was too easy... :-) Thanks a lot!